# Run JavaScript on browser, and process the results on server using R and Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am building a Shiny app involving simulation. The simulation itself takes up some resources, and it becomes a problem - a burden to the server - if the application is used by many users.

So, I was thinking of that hey, why not write the simulation part in JavaScript, run it in a browser, and then take the results to R. These results can be then processed on the server, plots can be drawn, etc.

Is this even possible?

Ok, let's illustrate this with a simple example:
Here is a JavaScript code that creates a list of numbers:
0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27
...and which should be run on the browser:

```
let numberlist = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  numberlist.push(i*3);
}
```

Now, if I want to plot this in Shiny, the UI. R file would probably look like this:

```
## ui.R ##
fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    #Sidebar panel can be empty, I think.
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("Plot"))
  )
)
```

But what about the server.R?

```
## server.R ##
function(input, output) {
  output$Plot <- renderPlot({
    #What should I put here to:
    #plot(c(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27))
    #i.e. to plot(c(JavaScript result))
  })
}
```

Is this even the way to do this, or should the results from the JavaScript code be taken to the server using the UI somehow?

Comment: Yes all of this is possible, have a look at https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html and https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html. Also, I think a lot of people take javasript for granted, it can be just as fast for a lot of operations, modern browsers are well capable of doing a lot of heavy lifting

Comment: I read that one through, but I could not really understand how to implement it in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case you describe, you can use `Shiny.setInputValue`. Create a subfolder **www** of your app folder, and put in this subfolder the following JavaScript file, say it is named **myjs.js**:

```js
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function () {
  let numberlist = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    numberlist.push(i * 3);
  }
  Shiny.setInputValue("numbers", numberlist);
});
```

Include this file in **ui.R**:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "myjs.js")),
  ......
)
```

Then in your **server.R** file, you will receive the list of numbers in `input[["numbers"]]`. It will be a list, not an atomic vector, so you have to use `unlist`:

```r
plot(unlist(input[["numbers"]]))
```

Now, say you want to set the length of your list of numbers in R, and send this length to JS. You need a *custom message handler* in this case:

```js
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function () {
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("getNumbers", function (l) {
    let numberlist = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      numberlist.push(i * 3);
    }
    Shiny.setInputValue("numbers", numberlist);
  });
});
```

Here is a scenario example:

```r
## ui.R ##
fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "myjs.js")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("length", "Length", min = 10, max = 100, value = 10, step = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("Plot"))
  )
)

## server.R ##
server <- function(input, output, session){

  observeEvent(input[["length"]], {
    session$sendCustomMessage("getNumbers", input[["length"]])
  })

  output[["Plot"]] <- renderPlot({
    req(input[["numbers"]])
    plot(unlist(input[["numbers"]]))
  })

}
```

Comment: I tried this out, and this worked like a charm.